# Utility to convert an arbitrary string to a .NET string

Tags: c#, .net, html, string

Is there a ***utility*** out there that will convert an arbitrary (or at least from an HTML doc) string into a nicely formatted C# string. The motivation for this is that I am doing a lot of unit tests of HTML docs, and I don't want to load them as files, but rather keep inline strings. I would love to paste some HTML into an editor, and output a reasonably looking C# string. 
For instance:

Convert this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/">
```

Into:

```
@"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" xml:lang=""en-US"" " +
"lang=""en-US"" xmlns:fb=""http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"" itemscope " +
"itemtype=""http://schema.org/"">"
```

If not, any thoughts on the corner cases for either HTML or .net strings that might be an issue? I am sure it is not as simple as `String.Replace("\"", "\"\"")` and busting the lines every 80 characters....

Even a plugin for Notepad++ or other editor would work.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do the 80 thing - id just do the quote doubling (for verbatim string literal)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem; why are you cutting and pasting HTML? If you are doing something with an "HTML doc" why not just open the doc as a file and do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Why do you want to split a string into concatenated strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [Smart Paster](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2004/05/25/Smart-Paster-1.1-Add-In---StringBuilder-and-Better-C_2300_-Handling.aspx)?

[image]

Visual Studio 2010 version [here](http://martinwilley.com/blog/2010/06/06/SmartPasteIn2010.aspx).